# Get dynamic numbers after specified word from result in python and store in database

Tags: python, web-crawler

Hi i want to get the numbers after 'citedby': in result.And the numbers changing per search.`

```
import scholarly
import re

m = next(scholarly.search_pubs_query('Perception of physical stability and center of mass of 3D objects'))
n = re.search('citedby (\d+)', m , re.IGNORECASE)`
```

I finded citation with scholarly and stored in m variable.Now i want to get the numbers after 'citedby':34567 .Example now i want to get the 34567 after 'citedby': .Please help me i am new to python.Added sample result.[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN8rq.png)
,[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG0Fr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) which returns all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

```
import re
m = "Example text 'citedby':34567"  # just an example.
n = re.findall(r"'citedby':\s?(\d+)", m, re.IGNORECASE)
print(' '.join(n))  # 34567
```

For your specific question:

```
import scholarly
import re

m = next(scholarly.search_pubs_query('Perception of physical stability and center of mass of 3D objects'))
n = re.findall(r"'citedby':\s?(\d+)", str(m), re.IGNORECASE)
print(''.join(n))  # 13
```

**Note**: Here `m` is `<class 'scholarly.Publication'>` object. `str(m)` makes it `<class 'str'>`. `findall` works only with strings.

Comment: Ok sir.How to print it

Comment: Thats working good sir.But it's not working when i add original result which m=m = next(scholarly.search_pubs_query('Perception of physical stability and center of mass of 3D objects')).

Comment: Is the input same as given in the image above?

Comment: Yes sir.the image is the m variable

Comment: Ok, I doubt there is a space after `:`. Try the updated one. Let's see.

Comment: Yes sir.But the error is in 3rd line sir.The m variable not working in the line which is starting with n=.Please view the another image i added in question sir

Comment: This is because `m` should be a string. Did you see a `"` around the test example I've provided? Make sure `m` is a string. Can you do `print(type(m))`?

Comment: I've no idea what that is.  For `findall`, you should be passing string. So when you do `print(type(m))`, it should be `<class 'str'>`.

Comment: Good news. I resolved the issue. See the latest edit. :)

Comment: Really Thank you sir.Worked 500%.Great sir thank you again

Comment: Cool. Happy coding :)